# Remove all divs where child element contains text greater than certain value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to remove all DIVs on my page with the class "property_container" that contain child elements with text that is less than a certain value (preferably using jQuery). I realize that the text inside the < p > child element will need to be converted into a numeric-only value in order to run the comparison method.

For the HTML, please see: http://jsfiddle.net/TqLs4/

Right now, as a step in that direction, I've tried:

```
$(".property_container")
    .find(".property:contains('200000')")
    .parent()
    .remove();
```

I know that the contains method is not what I need for my numeric if/then logic... Basically, I think I need something that looks like this junky pseudo-code:

```
$(".property_container")
    .find((".price")asNumber < 200000)
    .parent("property")
    .remove();
```

**Or, in natural language:**  If p.price (a child) of div.property_container has a numeric value (converted from text value contained within < p > tag) less than 200,000 then hide/remove the entire div.property_container.

Comment: You'll probably want to use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

Comment: Here's a variation that's quite similar to Barmar's http://jsfiddle.net/5qG9A/. Had it worked up before I noticed the question was answered.

Comment: @JohnL - Your solution works great as well, thank you! I didn't want to muddy up my main question, so I avoided posting about this next part:  How do I add another piece to the filter, so that the parent ".property_container" is only removed IF an additional child element also contains certain text (the third < li > of < ul.details >)?  (see:  http://jsfiddle.net/5qG9A/3/ )

Comment: To further filter the results, add an additional .filter call on the returned jQuery object or combine your logic statement so that return value from the .filter call contains the multiple clauses. It's starting to feel like a homework problem but I'll throw out one more example for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/T53HJ/

Comment: @JohnL I like the way you kept the function on price separate, and ran a filter on the result. Really helped me in making sense of what was happening. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

```
$(".property_container .price").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text().replace(/\D/g, ''), 10) < 200000;
}).closest(".property_container").remove();
```

I noticed in your fiddle that the text is not a number, it contains a dollar sign and comma separator, so I use `replace()` to remove them before parsing it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/TqLs4/2/)

Comment: Won't the removal of non-digits behave erratically if the decimal point appears in some cases but not others?